# Memory leak on Python SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, memory, sqlalchemy, memory-leaks

In this sample code, I track the memory usage every while loop.

In the first 50 loops, the 'Biggest DIFF' is `C:\Program Files\Python39\lib\tracemalloc.py:115` so that's not interesting (also it's not in my real problem). After 50 loops, `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\sqlalchemy\sql\elements.py:1551` takes over as biggest memory change, with the size growing every loop with 5KiB and the count growing 5 with every loop. That's the size of the df in this example.

The while loop was meant to have no memory leak, as you reassign `df` every time, then write it, then reassign, then write, and so on, and so on. But it leaks anyway, through SA.

Of course this is an example, I encountered this with a df.shape of [1000000,100] per loop. I don't care about 300 KiB.

What am I not understanding?

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa
import tracemalloc

tracemalloc.start(100)

engine = sa.create_engine(
    'mssql+pyodbc://' + UN + ':' + PW + '@' + HOST + '/' + DB +"?driver=ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server&Encrypt=Yes",
    pool_pre_ping=True,
    fast_executemany=True)

things = ['a', 'b', 'c']
do_count = 0

def get_some_data():
    df = pd.DataFrame([['Ajitesh', 84, 183, 'no'],
                       ['Shailesh', 79, 186, 'yes'],
                       ['Seema', 67, 158, 'yes'],
                       ['Nidhi', 52, 155, 'no'],
                       ['Ajitesh', 84, 183, 'no'],
                       ['Shailesh', 79, 186, 'yes'],
                       ['Seema', 67, 158, 'yes'],
                       ['Nidhi', 52, 155, 'no'],
                       ['Ajitesh', 84, 183, 'no'],
                       ['Shailesh', 79, 186, 'yes'],
                       ['Seema', 67, 158, 'yes'],
                       ['Nidhi', 52, 155, 'no'],
                       ['Ajitesh', 84, 183, 'no'],
                       ['Shailesh', 79, 186, 'yes'],
                       ['Seema', 67, 158, 'yes'],
                       ['Nidhi', 52, 155, 'no'],
                       ['Ajitesh', 84, 183, 'no'],
                       ['Shailesh', 79, 186, 'yes'],
                       ['Seema', 67, 158, 'yes'],
                       ['Nidhi', 52, 155, 'no'],
                       ['Ajitesh', 84, 183, 'no'],
                       ['Shailesh', 79, 186, 'yes'],
                       ['Seema', 67, 158, 'yes'],
                       ['Nidhi', 52, 155, 'no'],
                       ['Ajitesh', 84, 183, 'no'],
                       ['Shailesh', 79, 186, 'yes'],
                       ['Seema', 67, 158, 'yes'],
                       ['Nidhi', 52, 155, 'no']])
    return df


def write_the_data(tablename, collected_data):
    collected_data.to_sql(name=tablename, con=engine)

snapshot1 = tracemalloc.take_snapshot()
for thing in things:
    while do_count < 5000:
        df = get_some_data()
        write_the_data(tablename = thing, collected_data = df)
        do_count += 1
        print("Biggest DIFF: " + str(tracemalloc.take_snapshot().compare_to(snapshot1, 'lineno')[0]))
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `with` statement for SQLAlchemy connection to ensure it was properly closed.
2. Regularly flush or close SQLAlchemy sessions after their work is done.
3. Use more robust memory profiling tool like `memory-profiler` to better understand your program's memory usage.

Comment: Hmm, I come back on this tomorrow. This comment made me think about the representativity of the example, but really gave me some interesting food for thought. I will update.